# Please remove the excessive capitalization of certain paragraphs in the Terms of Service

Tags: feature-request, terms-of-service

I was browsing through the [Terms of Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) and noticed that [some parts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#warranties) are hard to read because they solely consist of capital letters. I can imagine there must be a US law stating that certain parts of a Terms of Service must be emphasized, but since we're on the Internet, [please don't shout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting). If those paragraphs do need to be emphasized, use italic or bold formatting and/or place a border around them.

Comment: Lawyers are paid per word. For capitalized words the rate is doubled. You don't want the lawyer to go bankrupt, do you?

Comment: Relevant: [Am I allowed to lowercase an ALL CAPS section in a license?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13342), [Can I change the caps to lowercase in licenses?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13), and [Can I remove all-caps and shorten the disclaimer on my License?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30329) -- the last one is answered by a pre-SE-employment version of Tim Post.

Comment: As pointed out by someone elsewhere, all-caps are hard to read, so lawyers put all nice-y wice-y bite-you-later stuff in all-caps and hope you won't read it.

Comment: Also relevant: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/743/do-disclaimers-need-to-be-capitalized

Comment: Personally, it feels rather archaic to have all caps in documents. Lowercase letters were invented over a thousand years ago and are pretty universally seen to make writing easier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carolingian_minuscule So why would we want to have anything on stack exchange that was deliberately harder to read. The practice can't reasonably be defended by saying it is because it's important because if it were that important, you'd really want it to be easier to read. We should be using bold instead of caps, since that helps with legibility and italics also make things harder.

Answer (score 2):

Since impatience is a virtue, I decided to write a userscript which does this:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange Terms of Service Normalizer
// @namespace   https://github.com/Glorfindel83/
// @description Removes excessive capitalization from Stack Exchange's Terms of Service.
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/legal/terms-of-service
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/legal/terms-of-service
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/legal/terms-of-service
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/legal/terms-of-service
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/legal/terms-of-service
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
  "use strict";

  let regex = /[A-Z][^a-z]{16,}?\.(\s|$)/g;  
  $("p").each(function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(match) {
      console.log(match);
      return "<b>" + match.charAt(0) + match.substring(1).toLowerCase() + "</b>";
    });
  });
})();
```

It decapitalizes proper nouns like Stack Exchange (you can expect that when using regular expressions), but otherwise it reads much better than the original:

[image]